# How can I solve $x^2.(y')^2-2.(x.y-3).y'+y^2=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the differential equation $x^2.(y')^2-2.(x.y-3).y'+y^2=0$ ? I don't have any idea of what method to use on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$x^2.(y')^2-2.(x.y-3).y'+y^2=0$$
$$(xy'-y)^2=-6y'$$
This is [Clairaut's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation):
$$y=xy'+f(y')$$
$$y=xy'\pm \sqrt {-6y'}$$

Comment: But this will give me four solutions, two of $y=xy' + \sqrt{-6y'}$ and two of $y=xy' - \sqrt{-6y'}$, won't it?

Comment: Yes surely because you have for both differential equations a singular solution and a general solution.  @RebecaLieYatsuzukaSilva